# Can you move a project from one Google Cloud Platform organization to another

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm new to Google Cloud so I'm hoping for some guidance around "organizations".
Can I move a project from one "organization" to another?  I'm starting up some projects under my personal GSuite organization, but I'll have to move them to a more professional organization and billing in the future once they are set up.

Is that possible?

Comment: are the organizations in the same domain? or are they different domains?
If they are in the same you can 
https://medium.com/google-cloud/moving-gcp-projects-between-iam-organizations-12c417915bcb

Comment: they would be different domains

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned on the [migration docs](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration) this is only possible by contacting [support](https://cloud.google.com/support).

Comment: Hello, is there a way to avoid contacting support for this? It feels kinda unfair to pay for a support package for a one-time action (which would be the case for me).

Comment: You could try asking the (free) billing support. I don't know any official word on this, but arguably this is in scope for billing as you might need this to use an orgs billing account

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your suggestion. I found another way around: I redeployed my Firebase projects into my other account and was able to transfer my buckets using the Transfer tool.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to develop apps in one account, and then move them to another Google Account, there might be a couple of possibilities.

- Use a free account which will put new Cloud Projects under "No organization"
- Intentionally create new Cloud Projects under "No organization"

You can give another Google account ownership of your Cloud Project and transfer ownership without the need for Google Support if the original Cloud Project is under the "No organization" category.

Google Cloud Projects created in a free/consumer account are NOT in an organization.  And therefore, if you want the G Suite account to get ownership of the Google Cloud Project from your free/consumer account, then you can do that without needing to get Google support involved.

To set up an organization, you need to go to: admin.google.com

https://admin.google.com/ac/accountchooser?continue=https://admin.google.com/

If you try to set up an organization in a free/consumer account, then you will get a message stating that it's for G Suite accounts only.

Your Cloud Projects in a free/consumer account will be put under the organization category of "No organization"